# VHDL - Cheapest-Fastest unsigned to signed binary number converter

Tags: vhdl, logic-gates, adder, conversion

We know that to convert unsigned to signed (precisely, I want to convert a pure binary into CA2 number) we must negate the unsigned number adding, then, + 1. In VHDL I can implement an inverter and an adder that manages the carry in. I have two numbers of 32 bits. Is there another way to implement the sum + 1 using anything cheaper? Is there a solution to manage the carry in using only logic gates?

Comment: No, that's for taking the negative of a number. Changing the signedness doesn't involve changing the bit pattern.

Comment: Yeah I know that the pattern is the same, but I need of negative number, I need to see it like a CA2 number

Comment: CA2, CA-2 or CA II may refer to :

    Carbonic anhydrase II, a human gene
    California's 2nd congressional district
    Hummel CA-2, an ultralight aircraft
    California State Route 2
    Ca II, a singly-ionized calcium that produces the H and K lines in the spectrum of many stars

Comment: In other words, what (precisely) is a "CA2 number"? It is not a common technical idiom.

Comment: CA2 : In French it would be "Complément à 2"="Two's complement".

Answer (score 4):

It really isn't worth worrying too much about this detail. Adding 1 to a number is such a common idiom in HDL that synthesis tools have highly-evolved methods for dealing wtih it. Also, most modern FPGAs have dedicated, hard-wired fast carry logic that does not consume logic cells, and that synthesis tools know how to take advantage of.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So, do u suggest to implement it in behavioral way and leave everything to synthesizer?

Answer (score 1):

If it's unsigned, it is by definition positive, therefore it's 2's complement equivalent is also positive, therefore the bit pattern representation is the same.

The one difficulty arises if its MSB is already set : then it is an unsigned too large to represent as a signed number of the same size. So the completely general answer is to sign-extend it into a 2's complement number at least 1 bit wider :

`my_signed <= '0' & my_unsigned;`